# problem with nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy

Tags: ros, rosjava, nxt-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!
I'm a researcher, I'm working with ROSJava and a NXT.
I'm trying to run LCPProxy.java but I have a problem.
After launching the node I get this output:

```
* Configurate ROS Node

*********************
* Running LCPProxy *
*********************

ROS Node Path: /home/camilla/my_workspace/nxt_lejos/nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy/
* Reading property file
Path: /home/camilla/my_workspace/nxt_lejos/nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy/nxt_lejos_ros/lcp_proxy.properties
BRICK-NAME: OKAY
CONNECTION: USB
YAML: NXT.yaml
Differential navigation features enabled
WHEEL_DIAMETER: 5.6
TRACK_WIDTH: 16.0
REVERSE: true
* Connecting with a NXT brick
Log.listener: Protocols = 1
Log.listener: Search Param = null
Log.listener: Searching for any NXT using USB
Found NXT: Unknown 001653079D95
ROS Node connected with a NXT brick
* Bind NXT brick with ROS
* Processing YAML file
YAML Path: /home/camilla/my_workspace/nxt_lejos/nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy/NXT.yaml
list size2
Type is ultrasonic
I found an ultrasonic  sensor description
ultrasonic_sensor
PORT_1
10.0
point1
Found NXT: Unknown 001653079D95
Failed to open connection to the NXT
```

It seems that the configurate and the connect steps succeed, but there is a problem in the bind() one.
In particular in during the first iteration of the for loop in processYAML().
Infact debbuging the code I saw that the last instruction called is:

```
us = new UltrasonicSensor(node, port);
```

But I can't figure out why and where there is a new attempt to connect to the brick which produces the last two lines of the output:

```
Found NXT: Unknown 001653079D95
Failed to open connection to the NXT
```

can you help me find a solution?or at least to understand where in the code and why there is the new attempt of connection?

I'm using a NXT with the traditional Lego firmware and a usb connection.

my YAML file is:

```
nxt_robot:
  - type: ultrasonic
    name: ultrasonic_sensor
    port: PORT_1
    min_range: 0.01
    max_range: 2.5
    desired_frequency: 10.0
  - type: differential_navigation_system
    name: pilot
    port: PORT_AC
    desired_frequency: 10.0
    track_width: 16.0
    wheel_diameter: 5.6
    reverse: true
```

(specifing another sensor or actuator as first element of the yaml file I get the same error, so the problem isn't specific of the ultrasonic sensor).

my lcp_proxy.properties file is:

```
NXT-BRICK: OKAY
CONNECTION-TYPE: USB
YAML-ROBOT-DESCRIPTOR: NXT.yaml
DIFFERENTIAL_NAVIGATION_FEATURES: true
WHEEL_DIAMETER: 5.6
TRACK_WIDTH: 16.0
REVERSE: true
```

Looking forward to hearing from you. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39344/problem-with-nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you have not flashed your NXT with the lejos firmware. Install [lejos](http://lejos.sourceforge.net/nxj-downloads.php) and flash the usb. See if the error is still there. I have arrived at this conclusion based on the fact that it is detecting it, but not getting information from it.

---

Instructions for flashing firmware can be found [here](http://lejos.sourceforge.net/nxt/nxj/tutorial/Preliminaries/GettingStartedLinux.htm).

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0